# How do you search by user if I don't know their user id?

Tags: support, search, users

How do you search by user if I don't know their user id? Different user, not myself.

And why doing a search like 'user:fgfgfblahblah apples' returns a ton of results when fgfgfblahblah doesn't exist!?

Comment: As user names aren't unique this wouldn't work. Can you not filter the users page to get their ID?

Comment: Sounds like a good place to promote `user:me` when you're trying to limit on your own posts.

Comment: @Arjan: I did say 'Different user, not myself'. I already know about user:me.

Comment: I know. I would have posted an answer if I thought it answered your question. And: this site is not just for you, sorry... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you search by user if I don't know their user id? Different user, not myself.

At https://stackoverflow.com/users, there is a search box where you can search by username. Once you have clicked through to the user profile*, the number in the URL bar is the user id.

*You can also reach the user profile by clicking on the user's username in any of his/her posts.

> And why doing a search like 'user:fgfgfblahblah apples' returns a ton of results when fgfgfblahblah doesn't exist!?

The reason is that searches are done using OR searches, so it returns any results where the word `apples` appear. It **only** limits the search to that particular user when a userid is passed, if it's anything else, it's treated as a string and not as a special parameter, so the traditional OR search is done.

Comment: OR or not I should get the resuts filtered correctly just like a SQL query. SQL doesn't make any assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

No idea on the second part, as for the first... I would try to find their ID.

Either find any post by that user or Click users and then type their name in to search.

Once you have a hyperlink, hover over it and copy down the number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the User Page

Search for their name

Click on their name

In the URL of the page you are directed to, the big long number is their user id.

For instance, yours is:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/**134444**/tony-henrich